# Recording mp3 on Windows 7 using SoX

Tags: windows-7, audio, sox

I'd like to have a SoX one-liner that would record 1 hour of audio to mp3. I'm on Windows 7. Is this possible?

Comment: @c0dev I saw that question before. This question is different because I want to record to mp3.

Comment: @RamRachum If the only difference between the questions is a file extension, I would consider it a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a one-liner, but a two-liner. Because SoX cant record mp3 you have to do it in two steps.

First, you record the audio as .wav-file:

```
rec recorded_track.wav 01:00
```

After that, you can convert it to a mp3-file by using SoX again.

```
sox infile.wav outfile.mp3
```

Comment: The problem with this is that there's a long processing step after recording. I want the conversion to be done in realtime while recording.